# como pegar o resultado de multi processos em uma lista no Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Estou criando um robo que em determinado momento precisa fazer multiplas requisições HTTP ao mesmo tempo e, retornar o resultado em uma lista. O código até então está assim:

```
import requests
import simplejson
from multiprocessing import Process

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'http://www.example.com'
        self.tracked_itens = ['foo', 'bar', 'bin']
        self.headers = {
            'accept'       : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'user-agent'   : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/'
                             '537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'
        }

    def make_search(self):
        body = { 'key:': 'example' }
        resp = requests.post(self.base_url, json=body, headers=self.headers)
        return simplejson.loads(resp.text)

    def make_search_item(self, id, item):
        resp = requests.get(f'{self.baseUrl}/{id}/{item}', headers=self.headers)
        return simplejson.loads(resp.text)

    def concurrent_search(self, id):
        processes = [Process(target=self.search_item, args(id, item) 
                     for item in self.tracked_items]
        [p.start() for p in processes]
        results = [p.join() for p in processes]

        return {k: v for d in results for k, v in d.items()} 

    def search_item(self, id, item):
        result = self.make_search_item(id, item)
        return {item: result}

    def search(self):
        result = self.make_search()

        if result['id']:
            results = self.concurrent_search(result['id'])
            return {'example_bot': results}
```

Meu problema é que, no método `concurrent_search` eu não consigo rodar todos os processos em paralelo e pegar o resultado deles. O que preciso fazer para que consiga retornar o resultado de todos os processos em uma lista?

Comment: já pensou em usar o módulo threading?

Comment: sim mas a intenção de usar o multiprocessing é pra conseguir extrair o maximo de multiplos núcleos no CPU. o threading cria múltiplas threads mas o python não usa multiplos CPU's quando usa esse módulo